# WooCommerce [products] shortcode not displaying pagination

Tags: php, woocommerce, pagination, product, shortcode

I am trying to display to display woocommerce products with pagination. it should show 12 products per page.
I am using the short code [products limit="-1" columns="4" paginate="true"] on a page. Right now it displays all products on the page with no pagination.
Can anyone help.

Answer (score 3):

The [WooCommerce Shortcode documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-9) says for `paginate` attribute:

> `paginate` – Toggles pagination on. Use in conjunction with `limit`. Defaults to `false`, set to `true` to paginate .

So that means that you need to limit the number of products to something smaller than the total number of queried products. So the `limit` attribute need to be a multiple of `columns` attribute value, so in your case something like `4`, `8`, `12`, `16,` `20`…

So for example using `[products limit="16" columns="4" paginate="true"]` will display on the page a grid of 4 x 4 products with the pagination…

> So `limit="-1"` disable the pagination logically.

*Usage in php code:* `echo do_shortcode('[products limit="16" columns="4" paginate="true"]');`